# FCM Android: background start is not allowed

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an application, which can be used to make calls. When one user wants to call another, my server POSTing this json to "https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/MyProject/messages:send

```
{
    "validate_only":false,
    "message": {
        "data": {
            "SomeData":"123"
        },
        "notification":null,
        "android": {
            "collapse_key":null,
            "priority":"HIGH",
            "ttl":"60s",
            "restricted_package_name":null,
            "data": {
                "SomeData":"123"
            },
            "notification":null
        },
        "webpush": {
            "headers": {
                "Urgency":"high"
            },
            "data":null,
            "notification":null,
            "fcm_options":null
        },
        "apns": {
            "headers": {
                "apns-priority":"10"
            },
            "payload":null
        },
        "token":"cU4RS3R142s:APA91bF6fDme6mxw9FcocLvXYepkpqYHbctZ0arEw43-6uhZCglyQ9qfndfmeeNE9oALkpzQ7boh47unQRoTMSUhy6ynddo6r8RcgYl9yuj07NCgDcSUfY4__YNSxpeGziXqQnDzGMZx",
        "topic":null,
        "condition":null
    }
}
```

It works fine while the application is in foreground and few minutes after I swipe it out from recent list. But after about 20 minutes `FirebaseMessagingService.OnMessageReceived` stops getting called and I'm getting this in logcat.

```
01-23 10:19:59.670: I/FirebaseInitProvider(7162): FirebaseApp initialization successful
01-23 10:19:59.717: I/MyTag(7162): Application: OnCreate
01-23 10:19:59.896: W/ActivityManager(1398): Background start not allowed: service Intent { act=com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT pkg=com.companyname.MyApp.Android cmp=com.companyname.MyApp.Android/com.companyname.myapp.android.notificationservice (has extras) } to com.companyname.MyApp.Android/com.companyname.myapp.android.notificationservice from pid=7162 uid=10179 pkg=com.companyname.MyApp.Android
01-23 10:19:59.897: E/FirebaseInstanceId(7162): Error while delivering the message: ServiceIntent not found.
```

And here is the code of my Application

```
        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            base.OnCreate();
            WriteLog("Application: OnCreate");
            InitializePlayService();
        }

        private void InitializePlayService()
        {
            FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(this);
            MyFirebaseIDService.SendRegistrationToServer(FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token);
        }
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: What OEM device is this and what API level is it running? (Note: A number of OEM's have implemented the background notification restrictions (in 8.0+, you should be able to white list the app within the Setting (Protected or Battery or ... ) This is also related to the background limit of execution in API 28+

Comment: @SushiHangover 7.1, but 5.1 doesn't work too. Xiaomi, and 5.1 is meizu. I've checked battery settings and permissions. WhatsApp does have some special permissions, but Telegram doesn't and Telegram works fine. I've checked Telegram sources, FCM part looks same as mine, but Telegram does a lot of things in application OnCreate and maybe somewhere else too.

Comment: What version of the Firebase library are you using?

Comment: @SushiHangover I'm using [Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging 60.1142.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging/60.1142.1). It says it's using Firebase 11.4.2, but I don't know how to verify that. My android sdk is up to date.